# Run Multi-parameters in Pycharm in Win10

Tags: python, pycharm, arguments

While writing an application parsing command line arguments in Pycharm in win10, I have to use the linux-style command like this:

```
python train.py --task language_modeling \
data-bin/wikitext-103 \
--save-dir checkpoints/ \
--arch transformer_lm_wiki103 \
--max-update 286000 --max-lr 1.0 --t-mult 2 --lr-period-updates 270000 --lr-scheduler cosine --lr-shrink 0.75 \
--warmup-updates 16000 --warmup-init-lr 1e-07 --min-lr 1e-09 --optimizer nag --lr 0.0001 --clip-norm 0.1 \
--criterion adaptive_loss --max-tokens 3072 --update-freq 3 --tokens-per-sample 3072 --seed 1 --fp16 \
--sample-break-mode none --skip-invalid-size-inputs-valid-test --ddp-backend=no_c10d
```

I think it's a boring way to write down all the **path-like arguments** in the "**Edit Configurations**" dialog.I also tried to use **BashSupport** plugins, writing down the above codes in a bash file ".sh", but I use a conda env interpreter for python, bash command can not recognize the path for the **conda env**..

[image]

[image]

So the present way to run the above code just filling in a long long line in the Terminal. Are there any efficient way to solve my embarrassing moments?

BTW, Pycharm version **is 2019.1 with anaconda 4.5.4+Python 3.6.10.**

Comment: Consider using https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7861-envfile which could load env variables from file

Answer (score 0):

You got your run configuration wrong.
You're running a shell script using python. Which is clearly said in error that you got.
Setup the correct configuration options:

`Run/Debug configurations -> Templates -> Shell script -> Create configuration`

[image: example of configuration to run shell script]